# Spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE - sleuth and mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have tried to sort this out for a week, but no luck at all. The issue is with the unit tests.

This is the class that I am trying to test:

```
import brave.Span;
import brave.Tracer;

@Service
public class InternetBackEndRestClient {

    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

  public PasswordJwtResponse generatePassworJwt(PasswordJwtRequest passwordJwtRequest, String traceId) throws LogonProxyException {
      log.info("{\"Starting method\": \"generatePassworJwt\", \"input\": {} }", passwordJwtRequest);

    Span newSpan = tracer.nextSpan().name("spanPasswordJwtResponse");
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I do the unit test? Brave.Tracer is a final class so that I cannot mock it. Is there anyway to set up a context? or mock Tracer?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InternetBackEndRestClientTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private InternetBackEndRestClient internetBackEndRestClient; 

   @Mock
   private Tracer tracer; 

   @Test
   public void generatePassworJwt_test() { 
      internetBackEndRestClient.generatePassworJwt(...);
      ....
   }
}
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: If you are using Mockito’s JUnit runner how is the application context getting created so that `@Autowired` injection will happen? Can you share a [minimal example](/help/mcve) of what you’re doing please?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InternetBackEndRestClientTest {

    private static final String TRACEID = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

    @InjectMocks
    private InternetBackEndRestClient internetBackEndRestClient;

    @Mock
    private Tracer tracer;
   @Mock
    private Span span;

    @Before
    public void setUp()  {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(tracer.nextSpan()).thenReturn(span);
        when(tracer.nextSpan().name("spanPasswordJwtResponse"))
           .thenReturn(span);
        when(span.start()).thenReturn(span);

        Tracing tracing = Tracing.newBuilder().build();
        doReturn(tracing.tracer().withSpanInScope(span))
             .when(tracer).withSpanInScope(span);
        doNothing().when(span).finish();

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can manually set the span and trace id using `TraceContext.newBuilder()` in a test and past the Tracer into the class being tested.

```
Tracer tracer = Tracing.newBuilder().build().tracer();
TraceContext ctx = TraceContext.newBuilder().traceId(10L).spanId(10L).build();
Span span = tracer.toSpan(ctx);
tracer.withSpanInScope(span);
```

This might be a bit lighter than mocking the `Tracer` class

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't complete so it's hard to identify everything that's not quite right, but one thing is that `@MockBean` will only work if you're using Spring Boot testing's infrastructure. That means that you need to be using `SpringRunner` to run the test and you also have to have enabled `@MockBean` support. The most common way to do that is with `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class InternetBackEndRestClientTest {
    // …
}
```

You can read more about `@MockBean` in the [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans).

Comment: Sorry, what do  you miss in the example? You can see the class that I am trying to test and the test class as well. I cannot use @MockBean, that's fine. But all I want to do is a unit test with mockito were I need to mock Brave.Trace, so that the instruction "Span newSpan = tracer.nextSpan().name("spanPasswordJwtResponse");" does not fail because the variable "tracer" is null.

Comment: Your example doesn’t show how you are getting the instance of `InternetBackEndRestClient` that you are testing. For the `@Autowired` on its `tracer` field to work, Spring needs to be creating it. That should happen if you use Spring’s testing infrastructure as described above. You then also need to have the `InternetBackEndRestClientTest` instance that Spring has created injected into your test class.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the example with the part you missed.

Comment: I have tried to use something like Tracing tracing = Tracing.newBuilder().build(); Tracer tracer = Mockito.mock(Tracer.class); tracer = tracing.tracer(); to create the context with the trace, but "tracer" is still null when I call the real class.

Comment: Your use of `@InjectMocks` means that Mockito will be creating `InternetBackEndRestClient`. It doesn't know anything about `@Autowired` so the `tracer` field is going to be `null`. If you want the value of the `tracer` field to be set, Spring needs to create the `InternetBackEndRestClient` instance. Using `@SpringBootTest` and `SpringRunner` as I have suggested here will achieve that.